# Passing arguments by value in Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, parameter-passing, fortran95

How do you keep the value of a function argument when you call it, without creating a new variable? This is, how can I pass the argument by value?

In this example code:

```
program what
  implicit none  
  integer :: a, b, c, d

  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3

  print *, a,b,c

  d = f(val(a), val(b), val(c))

  print *, d

  print *, a,b,c

  d = f(a, b, c)

  print *, d

contains

  function f(x,y,z) result(h)
    integer:: x,y,z
    integer :: h

    h = x+y+z
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
  end function
end program
```

when i call the function the second time, it only prints 0's.

Comment: BTW, please use some indentation in your codes. Here it does not matter, but it will make your code much more readable.

Comment: Usually I try to, but this code was just to test my doubt, so I did not put much effort on it; thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Fortran 95 there is no way. Except some very non-standard extensions, but they are not Fortran 95 nor any other Fortran, just extensions.

In Fortran 2003 use the `value` attribute.

```
function f(x,y,z) result(h)

integer, value :: x,y,z
```

The attribute requires explicit interface, but your example has it, so that is OK.

Comment: Prior to introduction of the value (on the calling side) and intent(in) (on the callee side) specifications, it was possible to pass (x),(y),(z) in the function call to avoid assignments in the function being returned to the caller.  There is also a value specification for the case where iso_c_binding is in effect, which is different (compatible with C call by value).

Comment: @tim18 You are not allowed to modify it then and that is crucial here.

Comment: Yes, some of those choices must or should complain about or prevent the modification, but it seems bad practice to modify an argument in this context.

Comment: There is nothing bad at all at modifying a pass by value argument. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: If they are passed by value what is the point of setting them to zero? They are either IN, INOUT, or OUT. So if they are in do not set them, and if they are INOUT or OUT then one expects the zero to come back to the caller.

Comment: @Holmz No, they not any intent, they are VALUE. Actually, one can combine intent(IN) with VALUE, but by default it is not any intent, it is just VALUE. The whole point od pass by value is that you can modify the argument and it is not changed for the calling code.

Comment: @tim18's mention of iso_c_binding should have been "bind(C)", a different thing.

Comment: @SteveLionel I actually somehow missed that part of his comment. Perhaps he added that using an edit. Definitely should be `bind(C)`.

Comment: @Vladimir I guess my point was (in an F90 context), what is the point of setting X, Y, Z to zero in the routine? (Other than to see that the 'values' were changed in the function)
Using INTENT would show at compile time that the INTENT was being violated, and PURE may also be combined.
At least I learned something about VALUE... But when would someone want to use VALUE? It looks similar (in intent) to using FIRSTPRIVATE in OpenMP?
There must be a place where this is useful... But I cannot get my head around when I should want it?

Comment: @Holmz Value is the default in C. Typically you modify the arguments at the beginning and not the end, but you can save a temporary variable if you need to multiply it by some coefficient or similar.

Comment: @VladimirF it doesn't HAVE To be `bind(C)` - that's only if you expect the caller to actually pass by value. Otherwise if a dummy argument has the `VALUE` attribute, an anonymous, writable copy of the actual argument is passed by reference, so assignments to it are thrown away when the routine exits.

Comment: `%val` is a Fortran 2003 thing ? How different is it (for allowed types) from passing by value ?

Comment: @Olorin `%val` is not any standard Fortran, it is a non-standard extension, The answer says *"Except some very non-standard extensions, but they are not Fortran 95 nor any other Fortran, just extensions."*