# Python does not recognize local variables in functions

Tags: python, pointers, function-call

I use python3.9 where I declared a variable `x`, which is an input to function `output = model(x)`. After the call `x` gets the same values as `output` variable. I expected that `x` before and after call should be the same, but it is not. The code behaves as if the `output` variable and local variables in the function `model` are pointers to `x`. Could you kindly explain this behavior? I've never met anything like that in Fortran, C/C++ and Matlab. Here is an example of my python code

```
import numpy as np

def model(aux):
    for i in range(0,len(aux)):
        aux[i] = np.sin( aux[i] ) + 1
    return aux

length = 5

x =  np.linspace(0,1,length)

print(' X variable  BEFORE the function call ')
print(x)

output = model(x)

print(' X variable  AFTER the function call ')
print(x)

print(' Output variable  AFTER the function call ')
print(output)
```

Ad here is what I get:

```
 X variable  BEFORE the function call 
[0.   0.25 0.5  0.75 1.  ]
 X variable  AFTER the function call 
[1.         1.24740396 1.47942554 1.68163876 1.84147098]
 Output variable  AFTER the function call 
[1.         1.24740396 1.47942554 1.68163876 1.84147098]
```

Shouldn't X variable  BEFORE and AFTER be the same?

Comment: This is a good guide on variable behavior in Python: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I'm not a numpy users... but if you know 'c' then it might be best to thinking of "x" as a pointer to your array. The parameter "aux" is pointing to the same memory space. So when you modify "aux" ... you would see the same updates in "x".  If you want aux to create a copy of the object, you would need to explicitly make a new object and copy the values.

Comment: Out of interest, isn't pass-by-reference the standard in Fortran, so that Fortran would behave similarly to Python in cases like this? For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848530/passing-arguments-by-value-in-fortran-95

Comment: Since you mention C++, Python pass-by-assignment semantics are exactly like passing around `T*`s (or perhaps more aptly `std::shared_ptr<T>`s) in C++.

Comment: Use `aux.copy()` before the loop assignment if you don't want this behavior.